# Allocating array of objects inside another class (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, memory-management

How can I allocate an array of object inside another class in it's constructor?

```
class BloomFilter
{
public:
    BloomFilter(double fp, size_t capacity);
private:
    size_t bf_m;
    size_t bf_k;
};

class RSig {
public:
    RSig(int32_t sizeL1, int32_t sizeL2, double bfFpRate) :
        numSlot_sig(sizeL1), numSlot_bf(sizeL2)
    {
        TL_sigMem = new BloomFilter(bfFpRate, numSlot_bf)[sizeL1];
    }

private:
    int32_t numSlot_sig, numSlot_bf;
    BloomFilter* TL_sigMem;
};
```

The code above gives me the following error:

```
In constructor 'RSig::RSig(int32_t, int32_t, double)’:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
         TL_sigMem = new TL_sigMem(bfFpRate, numSlot_bf)[sizeL1];
```

Preferably, I don't want to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want `TL_sigMem` to be an array of `BloomFilter` objects, or an array of `BloomFilter` pointers?

Comment: @manabreak I want to create array of `BloomFilter` objects.

Comment: It's severely unsmart to not use `std::vector` when it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array of objects, the syntax goes like this:

```
T* t = new T[<size>];
```

Where `T` is the type, `t` is the name of the array, and `<size>` is the size of the array. Now, in your situation, you would like to do this:

```
TL_sigMem = new BloomFilter[sizeL1];
```

This will create an array of `BloomFilter`s of size `sizeL1`. However, since your `BloomFilter` does not seem to have a default constructor, you'll need to either use `std::vector` and its `emplace_back()` function, whip out your own (rather complicated) approach, or to create an array of pointers instead:

```
BloomFilter** TL_sigMem;

TL_sigMem = new BloomFilter*[sizeL1];

TL_sigMem[0] = new BloomFilter(...);
```

Comment: I wonder why C++ doesn't allow allocating objects with non-default constructor. Could you explain the reason behind that?

Comment: @AryaMz I'm probably the wrong guy to give you a rationalization behind that! It's probably just the way it was originally designed. AFAIK, none of the modern C-like languages allow you to do that, though.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
#include <vector>

class RSig
{
public:
    RSig(double rate, std::size_t len) : TL_sigMen(len, BloomFilter(rate)) {}

private:
    std::vector<BloomFilter> TL_sigMem;
};
```

Comment: While technically correct, OP preferred a solution without the use of `std::vector`.